# After Onchange click function occur in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to make code for when i select the country then onchange function another trigger runs

```
<select name="a" id="a" onchange="plan()">
<option value="india">India</option>
</select>
<a onclick="selproduct(0)">Click</a>
 <script>
        function plan()
        {
        // when i select onchange then click function trigger///////////
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged java,php and .net? Great technology stack! I'm interested in your project.

Comment: Because Every Developer Knows about javascript

Comment: You can't get an onchange event with just one option, there's nothing to change ?

Comment: @adeneo can you not? even on a page load will it not fire the change event?

Comment: @no1_melman no it won't

Comment: No. `onchange` only fires when the element is changed by the user.

Comment: Why are you not just calling the `selproduct` in your `onchange`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

**html code**

```
<select name="a" id="a" onchange="plan()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="india">India</option>
</select>
<a onclick="selproduct(0)">Click</a>
```

**javascript**

```
 function plan()
        {
        document.querySelector("a").onclick();
        }
```